# Do I need to buy a license for a font to use it in an iPhone game?

Tags: fonts

I am using the Calibri font in a game that I am developing for the iPhone, and I'm unsure if I need to pay for a license for it. I use the font in Adobe Photoshop to generate textures that are then used and displayed at runtime. I will not embed the font binary in the game.

Do I need a license for the Calibri font? If I do, does anyone know about how much a font license would cost in a case like this?

---

I wrote Ascender Corporation and asked them about this issue. Here is the e-mail conversation:

> Ascender Corportation,
>
> The game I am making will only be
>   available on the Apple App Store for
>   the iPhone/iPod Touch platform. I am
>   not embedding the font in the game, I
>   am only using it in Adobe Photoshop to
>   generate textures that will be
>   displayed when the game is running.
>   Please, tell me about the license that
>   fits this circumstance.
>
> -Andrew

---

> Andrew,
>
> Thank you for the additional
>   information. We can provide you with a
>   license to distribute the Calibri
>   regular font in a single game title,
>   **on just the iPhone/iPod Touch
>   platform in one bitmap size for
>   $750**. Our standard license term
>   for game developers is a perpetual
>   term but for Calibri we can only
>   provide renewable two year terms. We
>   have reduced the license fee to
>   reflect the shorter term. You can
>   renew the license for additional two
>   year terms at your option. There are
>   no unit reporting requirements and the
>   license fee includes warranty and
>   indemnification from Ascender
>   Corporation.
>
> Please let me know if you have any
>   questions or if you want to proceed
>   with a license.   Best regards,
>   Ascender Corporation

This seems a little egregious, $750 for a single size? I am not even confident that the game I am making will make that much! Does this sound right?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the best way to think about this is that you are effectively signing up to a contract with a font foundry if you wish to use one of their fonts. This contract (license) could probably say anything it likes. It can say for example that you may not use the font on a tea-towel without paying an extra $1000, or that you have to give them your first born child if you use their font in a Flash file. I jest but you get the idea, the foundries are supplying a font and it is up to them what the terms/details of it's usage are.

Some foundries (maybe including Ascender here) are a bit over the top with their license fees. They are hot on getting what they can from sources like interactive games. Other foundries, (such as FontFont and CanadaType) are far more reasnoble and friendly to such usage. Yes, for full/rich vector based editable embedding of a font in an application, the foundry should be compensated fairly of course, but some foundries take the mickey and sadly the font industry cannot get its act together and be a little more co-ordinated in their approach to licensing for new media technologies. Instead what you end up with is lots of confusion and wildly different prices.

I personally dont think you should have to pay for a special license to just use images/bitmaps of the font characters in a game but what does it matter what I think, again you have to bear in mind it is up to the foundry to set the rules for their products. Therefore the people who are saying you do not owe them a dime for such usage, are sadly very wrong.

Obviously we can vote with our feet and not give certain foundries our business if we feel they are being unreasonable, right?

To the person who commented on fonts not being copyrightable, that is clearly a load of rubbish. Also, it's worth noting that fonts which arrived pre-installed on your PC or came with software you bought, is not being given away free. Im not too sure where the 'license' for these fonts resides but there will be one!

Also, as someone else mentioned check out fontsquirrel.com if you are looking for something simple and cheap/free. I'd also recommend FontFont.com for excellent quality fonts

Comment: It seems the issue over copyright is the distinction between the font-file.ttf and a bitmap representation of the font, the "font face". From the little I've read, the former is covered by copyright (in the US, UK, elsewhere?) but the latter isn't. [Wikipedia: Intellectual property protection of typefaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patent_and_Copyright_Protection_of_Fonts)

Comment: It's interesting that CanadaFont was mentioned here as "far more reasonable".  I checked them out and their license is for using a font in 1 app is $2500.

Answer (score 12):

According to [the Free Software Foundation](http://www.fsf.org/blogs/licensing/20050425novalis), "[I]n the US... [a] font face -- that is, the look of a font, is not copyrightable."

So there you go.

Answer (score 7):

I am not a lawyer, but Calibri is a standard font. Your work is derived from that font, so no you do not owe any royalties on it.

Generally, it would be up to the foundry to price the royalties.

**Edit** I believe they are confused that you are making a bitmap with each shape of the letter and using that to render text.

I didn't read this, but Adobe is a good resource on the matter.

http://www.adobe.com/aboutadobe/antipiracy/ff_faq.html

Answer (score 5):

I am not a lawyer, but I don't think you owe them a dime.

You state that you are only using the font to produce "textures" -- presumably meaning that the font is used to render specific characters into a bitmap image, quite possibly an image that contains other, original elements -- and that you are not redistributing the font "binary".

I would further guess that you are not rendering each and every character of the font into a separate bitmap and then combining those bitmaps *on the fly* in your app to produce the "textures." (That would probably cross the line and be considered "redistributing the font," albeit in a different form.)

Suppose that you were an artist, commissioned to create a poster for an event. You happened to use Calibri font in Photoshop to spell out the words "Tickets go on sale September 27" on the poster. Does this mean you owe the creator of Calibri a royalty, because you are "redistributing" multiple posters, and perhaps re-using the poster image on a website? Absolutely not, because you are not redistributing the font itself -- that is, all of the independent characters, in a way that they can be recombined arbitrarily.

[As for their pricing, it's entirely up to them to set the price at $750 or $75K or $7, and none of those numbers is more "right" than any other. But it sounds like they want to sell you the right to redistribute the entire font (all the characters) as a set of bitmaps. That is waaay different from your simple use of the font to create static images, a right that you already have paid for with your Photoshop license.]

Update: [Typography.com](http://www.typography.com/ask/faq.php) appears to agree with me:

> **Bitmap graphics** (gif, jpg, png)
>   There's no difference between using a
>   font to create a printed page and
>   using it to create a pixellated image.
>   As long as the person creating the
>   images has licensed the fonts, no
>   additional license is needed.

Comment: This bit of your answer is incorrect:
``I would further guess that you are not rendering each and every character of the font into a separate bitmap and then combining those bitmaps on the fly in your app to produce the "textures." (That would probably cross the line and be considered "redistributing the font," albeit in a different form.)''
Font copyrights are on the instructions to create the bitmaps, not on the bitmaps themselves. You can do whatever you want with rendered bitmaps, including assembling them to create words. (In the U.S. anyway.)

Comment: http://nwalsh.com/comp.fonts/FAQ/cf_13.htm

Comment: Relevant quote from jesmith's link: "The U.S. Copyright Office holds that a bitmapped font is nothing more than a computerized representation of a typeface, and as such is not copyrightable"

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, you're allowed to use them royalty-free without restriction, you just can't redistribute them.

Answer (score 1):

Well I couldn't find anything conclusive. When in doubt, there are [open source fonts available](http://openfontlibrary.fontly.org/).

Comment: there are a whopping 4 fonts on that website! Font Squirrel is a much larger resource: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/

Answer (score 1):

Under US law, bitmap fonts cannot be copyrighted. Therefore the foundry has no ability to enforce any restrictions on your use of bitmaps you create. Feel free to send them money if you like, but you are under no legal obligation to.

Stroked fonts are a different story altogether. The strokes are considered a "program" under US law, and therefore can be copyrighted. Their use can therefore be restricted by a software license agreement.

But the workflow you describe would not result in any copyright infringement.

Comment: xhttp://nwalsh.com/comp.fonts/FAQ/cf_13.htm

Answer (score 0):

See a lawyer.  If you're in the US, get in touch with your local Bar Association.  Tell them your issue and let them set you up with a consultation.

Of course, a few hours of a lawyer's time can easily run over $750, so if you're going to want any sort of representation or formal legal advice it could be cheaper to pay the $750, but it'll be worth the initial consulting fee to get a professional to explain the law to you.